# Prove that $T_p$ is Self Adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace

> Let $P \in M^{\Bbb C}_{n \times n}$ an invertible matrix. Let $T_p$ be a linear transformation $T_p: M^{\Bbb C}_{n \times n} \to M^{\Bbb C}_{n \times n}$ such that: $$T_p(X)=P^{-1}XP$$. for every $X \in M^{\Bbb C}_{n \times n}$. The scalar (inner) product is $<A,B>=tr(B^*A)$

Prove that if $P$ is self-adjoint, then $T_p$ is self-adjoint.

**My question**

Let $*$ be the self-adjoint operator. Should I prove $(T_p)^*=T_p$ OR $T_{p^*}=T_p$?

I think I should solve that with inner-product arithmetic but I don't know which term I have to prove.

**Assuming I have to prove $(T_p)^*=T_p$**, I am stuck here:

$$tr \left( B^*P^{-1}XP\right) =tr \left(P^{-1} X^*PB \right)$$

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: The former. The latter is automatically true since $P^* = P$ in your hypothesis.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thank you. can you please see my edit to see where I'm stuck?

Comment: What is $B$ here?

Comment: What is your scalar product on $M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb C}$? After your edit: Aha, the Hilbert Schmidt one. Cameron: $B$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I presume you are using the Frobenius norm here?

Comment: $<A,B>=tr(B^*A)$ is my inner (scalar?) product.

Comment: @copper.hat not sure what Frobenius norm is.

Comment: You are using the  Frobenius norm.

Comment: Write down $\langle T_p(X),Y\rangle$ and $\langle X,T_p(Y)\rangle$ and use that $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$.

Comment: What do you do there? I don't even understand your first equation. Further: what does $\rightarrow$ mean here? And what is $B*X$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp forget I even wrote it :)

Comment: @Alan: The Frobenius norm is the norm induced by the inner product above. It is the Euclidean norm if you look at the matrix as a big long vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So starting from $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(B^* A)$, we want to show that

$$ \langle T_p X,B \rangle = \langle X,T_p B\rangle \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{tr}(B^* T_p X) = \operatorname{tr}((T_p B)^* X).$$

We have that $\operatorname{tr}((T_p B)^*X) = \operatorname{tr}((P^{-1}BP)^*X) = \operatorname{tr}(P^*B^* (P^{-1})^*X)$. But now $P^* = P$ and $(P^{-1})^* = P^{-1}$ so this reduces to $\operatorname{tr}(PB^*P^{-1}X)$. Now use the fact that traces are cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle X,T_p(Y) \rangle &=& \operatorname{tr}(X^* P^{-1} Y P ) \\
&=& \operatorname{tr}(PX^*P^{-1} Y) \\
&=& \operatorname{tr}((P^{-1}XP)^* Y) \\
&=& \langle P^{-1}XP,Y \rangle 
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $(T_p)^* X = P^{-1}XP = T_p X$.

Comment: The third equality is false. Just edit to get it right.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Thanks for spotting that!